# Representing a subnet mask and return the CIDR value

Tags: c, ipad, masking, pack, unpack

New to coding and stuck on this IP subnetting thing.

I have the code built out for a program running on 2 c files and a h file. When I try running, it says my IP address is invalid, but then I enter for example 10.152.34 that will work. But if I enter 10.152.34.67 then it says invalid.
It also says my subnet mask is invalid no matter what I put in. It should accept binary and subnet mask values (periods included) and return binary numbers.

e.g.

```
IP Address:  00001010 11000101 10011000 00001000 = 10.197.152.8
```

Pretty sure my CIDR function (or lack there of) is part of the problem, but I'm honestly just lost at this point. I have tried two versions of this code - the first one got mad because I had declared functions several times. This one seems to at least get past compiling, but doesn't give the desired result. Any help or thoughts on  fixing the IP and subnet mask portion and building the CIDR function would me AMAZING!

---

## Main Function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*This program will display the IP address and subnet mask in binary
 format. It will also display the network address in binary and in
 CIDR formats.
*/

int main(void)
{

int i;
int ip[4];
int sub[4];
char *piece;
char ip_str[50];
char ip_str2[50];
char sub_str[50];
char sub_str2[50];

                
printf("Enter an IP address: ");
scanf("%s", & ip_str);
strcpy(ip_str2, ip_str);
   if(!ipVal(ip_str2))
   {
    printf("The ip address you entered (%s) is not valid.\n", ip_str);
    return 1;
   }
piece = strtok(ip_str, ".");
 i = 0;
while(piece && i <= 4)
{
 ip[i++] = atoi(piece);
 piece = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
printf("\n Enter the subnet mask: ");
scanf("%s", &sub_str);
strcpy(sub_str2, sub_str);
if(!subVal(sub_str2))

{
printf("The subnet address you entered (%s) is not valid.\n", sub_str);
return 1;
}

piece = strtok(sub_str, ".");
i = 0;
while(piece && i < 4)

{
sub[i++] = atoi (piece);
piece = strtok(NULL, ".");
}

printf("\n");

bit_print(pack(ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]));
bit_print(pack(sub[0], sub[1], sub[2], sub[3]));

printf("IP Address: %s\n", ip_str);
printf("Subnet Mask: %s\n", sub_str);

printf("\nThank you for using ip158.\n");


}
```

**# ipfunc.c**

```
#include "ipfunc.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int val_digit(char *ptr)
{

while(*ptr)
{
if(!isdigit(*ptr))
 {
return 0;
}
ptr++;
 }
return 1;
}

int valid_sub(int num)
{
int found = -1;
int sub[] = {0, 128, 192, 224, 240, 248, 252, 254, 255};
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
if (num == sub[i])
{
found = i;
break;
 }
}

if (found != -1)
{
return 1;
else {
return 0;
 }
}

int pack (int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
int p = a;

p = (p << CHAR_BIT) | b;
p = (p << CHAR_BIT) | c;
p = (p << CHAR_BIT) | d;
return p;
}
char unpack(int p, int k)
{
int n = k * CHAR_BIT;
unsigned mask = 225;

mask <<= n;
return ((p & mask) >> n);
}

int ipVal(char *ip_str)
{
int i, num, dec = 0;
char *buff = ip_str;
char *ptr;

if (buff == NULL)
return 0;
ptr = strtok(buff, ".");
if (ptr == NULL)
return 0;

while (ptr)
{
if (!val_digit(ptr))
return 0;
num = atoi(ptr);

if (num >= 0 && num <= 255)
{
ptr = strtok(NULL, ".");
if (ptr != NULL)
dec++;
else
return 0;
}
if (dec != 3)
return 1;
}

int subVal(char *sub_str)
{
int i, num, dec = 0;
char *ptr;

if (sub_str == NULL)
return 0;
ptr - strtok(sub_str, ".");
if (ptr == NULL)
return 0;
while (ptr)
{
if (!val_digit(ptr))
return 0;
num = atoi(ptr);
if (valid_sub(num))
{
ptr = strtok(NULL, ".");
if (ptr != NULL)
dec++;
else
return 0;
}
if (dec != 3)
return 0;
return 1;
}

int cmpCIDR(unsigned int p) {}
```

**# ipfunc.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>

  
int pack(int a, int b, int c, int d);
char unpack(int p, int k);
int ipVal(char *ip_str);
int subVal(char *cub_str);
int cmpCIDR(unsigned int p);`
```

Thank you so much!!

I've tried two sets of different code - this set gave me the least errors and at least got past compiling stage and the program began to run. I'm expecting the program to request user input for the IP and subnet mask, and to return the values in binary.

Comment: Start by using `inet_pton`. Also you should check the net mask by converting to 32 bit unsigned integer, and checking the pattern by bitshifting.

Comment: Not sure I understand what any of that means @Cheatah